# Eigen Library: Assertions failed in a template

Tags: c++, eigen, assertions

I have a templated function, which should generate a compile-time known fixed-size Vector, dependent on the template parameter:

```
template <int nSize> 
Eigen::Matrix<double, nSize, 1> myFunc()
{
    switch(nSize){
    case 2: return ExternalLibrary::generate_Vector_2d();
    case 3: return ExternalLibrary::generate_Vector_3d();
    }
}
```

However, when i compile this code, i get a failed assertion, because the Vector_2d size doesn't fit the 3d size:

```
Eigen::Vector3d testVector3d = myFunc<3>(); // failed, because 3d doesn't fit the theoreticelly possible 2d
```

Basically, the failed assertion is understandable, but of course this will never be an issue at runtime. How can i bypass this failed assertion? Or is there a more elegant way than the switch condition?

Thank you!

Comment: why not [fully specialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) the func template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare the template function and don't define it, then define two specializations:

```
template <int nSize>
Eigen::Matrix<double, nSize, 1> myFunc();

template <>
Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> myFunc<2>()
{
    return ExternalLibrary::generate_Vector_2d();
}

template <>
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> myFunc<3>()
{
    return ExternalLibrary::generate_Vector_3d();
}
```

The compiler, while it will eliminate dead code as an optimization, **must verify the validity of the dead code anyway**, which means it must ensure that the return type of `ExternalLibrary::generate_Vector_3d()` can be converted to `Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>`, even though it can be proven that that return statement can't be executed.  Because this conversion is not allowed, you get a compile-time error.

By separating out the two return statements into separate specializations, you eliminate this problem as it removes the `return ExternalLibrary::generate_Vector_3d();` statement from a function that *could* return something other than an `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>`.

---

Note that using `myFunc()` with an `nSize` other than 2 or 3 will cause a link-time error.  We can move this error to compile-time by providing a body that will fail to instantiate, but that (ostensibly) depends on `nSize` so that the compiler won't try to instantiate it before it is used:

```
template <int nSize>
Eigen::Matrix<double, nSize, 1> myFunc()
{
    // With C++11, the following line provides a more useful diagnostic. If
    // you don't have C++11 support, remove it and the bad return statement
    // will do the job, albeit with a more cryptic error message.
    static_assert((static_cast<void>(nSize), false), "Invalid template parameter nSize");

    return static_cast<class INVALID_NSIZE_PARAMETER**********>(nSize);
}
```

This will provide a diagnostic pointing to the incorrect use of `myFunc()`.  For example, without C++11 support you would see something like:

```
main.cpp:12:12: error: cannot cast from type 'int' to pointer type 'class INVALID_NSIZE_PARAMETER **********'
    return static_cast<class INVALID_NSIZE_PARAMETER**********>(nSize);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:29:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'myFunc<4>' requested here
    myFunc<4>();
    ^
```